# How to create table having text fiels with drupal 7 web form module

Tags: drupal-7

I am using drupal 7 web form module.I want to create a form with a table having text fields.Can any one help me to do this.Is there any particular module available in drupal7 to customize a form to create a table

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Fieldset** type to create a webform table component