# Drupal Webform item description showing nicely?

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-webform

On a *[drupal](http://drupal.org)* site I have a *[webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform)* with [table-like sorted inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12058923/1589669). Its hard to display long descriptions nicely. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I made to attach descriptions collapsed to labels (added as *node* description):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $(".form-item:has(div.description)").children("label").append(function(){
            $(this).parent().children('.description').hide();
            return '<sup><a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().parent().find(\'.description\').toggle();" title="'+$(this).parent().children('.description').text()+'"><strong>?</strong></a></sup>';
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Sandbox here: http://jsfiddle.net/eapo/3ubec/

Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you are using drupal 7, you should be using drupal behaviors instead of document.ready

Comment: Thank You, its in this casse is drupal 6.